# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on ESXi 6.7 white screen after boot

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, vmware

I am trying to install 18.04.2 LTS Server on ESXi 6.7.

I get to the boot menu, select the language and start the installation.
Next thing is I get a pretty bright screen with artifacts.

When I try to use the text based installer It warns me about the incomplete translation and when I accept, the screen stays the same and I can't do anything anymore.

- I exposed all CPU features
- I increased the graphical memory size from 4 up to 64
- I enabled 3D acceleration
- I set booting to UEFI

Nothing helped.

The VMs have >4GB RAM, 2 and 4 cores, 20-32 GB HDD for the primary hard drive on SSD.

- I re-downloaded the server (not live) installation ISO
- I tried starting the VM without optical drive attached, attaching it at runtime and sending CTRL+ALT+DEL as we had experiences with other VMs on different servers not detecting devices (HDD for example) correctly without this procedure (ESXi 6.5)

I can't get the installation started and these machines will be mission critical and I have no idea whats causing this.

Thanks much for any help.

Comment: What kind of host system / hardware are you using?

Comment: Supermicro X11DPi-N, 128GB RAM, 1x (currently) Intel 4110T, Samsung 970 Pro for the OSes, WD RED RAID for data. on an Areca controller (currently not initialized, the system is new)

Comment: I tried 18.04 and 18.04.1, too. I have the same problem on all 3 images.

Comment: 16.04.6 works just fine.